# Spilt a string and appending

Tags: python, string

I have a string for example:

> "112233445566778899"

How can I spilt it to the following pattern:

> "\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99"

I could spilt the string with following commands, but I could find out a way to append "\x" to the them:

```
s = "112233445566778899"
[s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
```

Comment: `lst=['\\x'+s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]`

Comment: If you want the string that would be generated from that literal: `''.join([chr(int(s[i:i + 2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(s), 2)])`

Comment: @StephenRauch Why the `chr(int(...))` dance?

Comment: @JohanL, it is not always clear if someone wants the string that is the 4 charters of `\x11` or if they want the string of one character that the string literal `\x11` would produce from source code. The `chr(int(..., 16))` dance will produce the string that the string literal would produce.  IE: one byte per two hex characters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string will always have an even length, you always want to split the string into pairs, and that your string is already ordered:

```
>>> string = "112233445566778899"
>>> joined = ''.join(r'\x{}'.format(s + s) for s in string[1::2])
>>> print(joined)
\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99
>>>
```

Comment: What about using regular expressions ?

Comment: @Bodhi94 You _could_ use them. But unless the OP needs something more specific or complex, I see little reason to use them. They don't need the overhead of regex for something trial like this. [Obligatory reading](https://xkcd.com/1171/) ;-)

Comment: I notice our string has the format = "x31x32x33x34x35", when i use your code it show xxx xxx xxx ... Can you fix it for new format?

Comment: Can you edit your answer for output like "x31xc0xb0x01x31xdbxb3x20xcdx80". I want the mentioned string turn to something like "\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xb3\x20\xcd\x80"

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "112233445566778899"
a = [r'\x' + s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
print(''.join(a))
```

Comment: It's output : ['\\x11', '\\x22', '\\x33', '\\x44', '\\x55', '\\x66', '\\x77', '\\x88', '\\x99']
but i want the output be like : "\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99"

Comment: Hold on, will fix

Comment: No need to fix , array is ok, just needs to be merged into string

Comment: Can you edit your answer for output like "x31xc0xb0x01x31xdbxb3x20xcdx80". I want the mentioned string turn to something like "\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xb3\x20\xcd\x80"

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following edit to your code:

```
...
[r"\x"+s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
...
```

Notice that this will return two forward slashes:

```
['\\x11', '\\x22', '\\x33', '\\x44', '\\x55', '\\x66', '\\x77', '\\x88', '\\x99']
```

This is because of Python escaping the `\` using the escaping character `\`.

When using the string you will notice that one of the `\` disappears:

```
>> x = ['\\x11', '\\x22', '\\x33', '\\x44', '\\x55', '\\x66', '\\x77', '\\x88', '\\x99']
>> print(x[0])
>> '\x11'
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer for output like "x31xc0xb0x01x31xdbxb3x20xcdx80". I want the mentioned string turn to something like "\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xb3\x20\xcd\x80"

Answer (score 0):

I think using regular expressions can you the best. Because it can find doubled characters anywhere on the string.

```
>>>import re
>>>string = "112233445566778899" 
>>>x = ''.join(r'\x{}'.format(s) for s in re.finditer(r'(\w)\1',string))
>>>x
'\\x11\\x22\\x33\\x44\\x55\\x66\\x77\\x88\\x99'
>>> print(x)
\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99
```

Comment: It doesn't work bro:         string = str(feed)
        x = ''.join(r'\{}'.format(s) for s in re.finditer(r'(\w)\1',string))
        print(x)

Comment: Can you edit your answer for output like "x31xc0xb0x01x31xdbxb3x20xcdx80". I want the mentioned string turn to something like "\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xb3\x20\xcd\x80"